# 'TypeError: o is not a function' when connect to discord voice channel (discord.js v13)

Tags: discord.js

I am recently trying to add the feature of @discordjs/voice to my discord bot but seems unable to join the voice channel. Here is the code written for when triggered by `${prefix}/music` command

```
    const voice_discord = require('@discordjs/voice');
    
    var VC = msg.member.voice.channel
    if (!VC)
        return msg.reply("You must be in Voice Channel")
    const player = voice_discord.createAudioPlayer()
    const resource = voice_discord.createAudioResource('music/xxx.flac')
    const connection = voice_discord.joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: VC.id,
        guildId: VC.guild.id,
        adapterCreater: VC.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    })
    player.play(resource)
    connection.subscribe(player)
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: o is not a function
at new G (C:\dcbot\node_modules\@discordjs\voice\dist\index.js:8:7254)
at Oe (C:\dcbot\node_modules\@discordjs\voice\dist\index.js:8:12358)
at Object.gt (C:\dcbot\node_modules\@discordjs\voice\dist\index.js:8:12577)
```

looking into `@discordjs\voice\dist\index.js` where the 'o' is not resolved but I have no idea what could I do...

PS there are the version of the discord.js

```
├── @discordjs/opus@0.5.3 
├── @discordjs/voice@0.8.0
├── discord.js@13.6.0     
├── ffmpeg-static@4.4.1   
├── sodium@3.0.2
```

Comment: It may be helpful to provide the exact versions of the `discord.js` & `@discordjs/voice` libraries that you are using.

Comment: Seems like its unhappy with that `voiceAdapterCreator`, but I do not know how to fix that (could try with `msg.guild.voiceAdapterCreator` though).